# magento Shopping Cart is Empty on safari & explorer browsers when i add products on these browsers

Tags: magento-1, addtocart, shopping-cart

My store Shopping Cart is Empty is always empty when I use safari browser and internet explorer to view my store and add to cart from this browser.
Please, can anyone help me regarding this? What can be the cause and how to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm new in Magento but facing the similar problem (configurable products can't be added to cart). The page will hang for about a minute and it will give a time-out, varien object error message. Can I check with you what are the differences between the original and commented codes? What do I need to fill in exactly at the commented codes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue causes due to session cookie management.

For resolving this issue go to **System->Configuration->Web->Session cookie management** section, and set

> cookie lifetime: 0
>
> cookie path:
>
> cookie domain:
>
> Use Http only: yes
>
> cookie restriction mode: no

and comment the following path file content
file path: **/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php**

**Orignal code:-**

```
 //session cookie params
      $cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
           'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
           'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
          'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );
```

**Commented code:-**

```
//session cookie params
      $cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
          //  'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
          //  'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
          //  'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );
```

Also, clear the safari browser cache, then shopping cart empty problem get resolved.

Comment: These three values are configurable in "web > session cookie management". Fix your configuration instead of hacking the core like this.